# Logging with EventSubscribers in TypeORM: Accessing HTTP context and retrieving Where conditions

Tags: mysql, express, logging, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am using TypeORM and MySQL for my database.

I want to log whenever certain data is updated using EventSubscriber, and for that purpose, I plan to use

```
beforeUpdate?(event: UpdateEvent<MyEntity>): Promise<any> | void {}  
afterUpdate?(event: UpdateEvent<MyEntity>): Promise<any> | void {}
```

(I plan to create a separate table for logging)

However, there are two things that I need help with:

1. I want to access the HTTP Context object within the EventSubscriber. This is because the Request object contains user information that I want to use to register the author.
2. I want to know the WHERE condition. I am using queryBuilder to write queries, but I don't know where the WHERE condition is in UpdateEvent. It would be great if I could find out where the WHERE condition is.

Thank you for your help!